# _tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!entry2 insert index text"

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a numerical calculator where I am converting decimal to binary, and vis a vis ,with all the conversions together into an application using tkinter ,This is working properly , but I was getting an error where I did not understand what ,I will include the code below,

PS : If anyone use the code ,give me credits

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[ ]:


from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Numerical Converter')
root.config(bg="DarkKhaki")
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
xhh= 340
yhh= 270
xx = int(int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2)- int(xhh/2))
yy = int(int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2)- int(yhh/2))
root.geometry(f"{xhh}x{yhh}+{xx}+{yy}")

submenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label='About', menu=submenu)
submenu.add_command(label='This application is created by Pradyumna P Rao.\n\nTo get the code of the application visit www.github.com/pradyumnaprao/numbersystemconversions')

Label(root, text='Binary', bg='DarkKhaki',font=("gabriola",20,"bold",'italic')).grid(row=0, column=0,sticky=W)
e_b = Entry(root, width=25, borderwidth=5, bg='AntiqueWhite',font=("helvetica",10,"bold"))
e_b.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=20, pady=10)

Label(root, text='Decimal  ', bg='DarkKhaki',font=("gabriola",20,"bold",'italic')).grid(row=1, column=0,sticky=W)
e_D = Entry(root, width=25, borderwidth=5, bg='AntiqueWhite',font=("helvetica",10,"bold"))
e_D.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=20, pady=10)

Label(root, text='Octal', bg='DarkKhaki',font=("gabriola",20,"bold",'italic')).grid(row=2, column=0,sticky=W)
e_O = Entry(root, width=25, borderwidth=5, bg='AntiqueWhite',font=("helvetica",10,"bold"))
e_O.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=20, pady=10)

Label(root, text='Hexadecimal', bg='DarkKhaki',font=("gabriola",20,"bold",'italic')).grid(row=3, column=0,sticky=W)
e_H = Entry(root, width=25, borderwidth=5, bg='AntiqueWhite',font=("helvetica",10,"bold"))
e_H.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=20, pady=10)


# Binary to deci, octal and hexa

def popup(labeltext):
    pop  =Toplevel(root)
    pop.title('ERROR')
    xh= 180
    yh= 90
    x = int(int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2)- int(xh/2))
    y = int(int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2)- int(xh/2))
    pop.geometry(f"{xh}x{yh}+{x}+{y}")
    label =Label(pop,text=labeltext, font=('calibre',10,'bold'))
    label.pack(pady=10)
    my_frame = Frame(pop)
    my_frame.pack(pady=5)
    b1=Button(my_frame,text="Okay",bd=1,bg='DarkOrchid',command=lambda:pop.destroy())
    b1.grid(row=0,column=1)
def btd(number):
    global conv
    conv = "bintodeci"
    number=str(number)
    leng = len(number)
    b = 0
    for i in number:
        c = int(i) * pow(2, leng - 1)
        b = b + c
        leng = leng-1
    return b

def bintodeci(number):
    bin_set= {'0','1'}
    x = number
    x=set(x)
    if bin_set == x or x == {'0'} or x == {'1'}:
        return btd(str(number))
    else:
        e_D.delete(0, END)
        e_O.delete(0, END)
        e_H.delete(0, END)
        popup("Enter 0s and 1s only")

def bto(number):
    b = bintodeci(number)
    s=''
    while b > 0.1:
        a = b % 8
        b = b/8
        s = s+str(int(a))
    return int(s[::-1])

def bintooctal(number):
    bin_set= {'0','1'}
    x = number
    x=set(x)
    if bin_set == x or x == {'0'} or x == {'1'}:
        return bto(str(number))
    else:
        e_D.delete(0, END)
        e_O.delete(0, END)
        e_H.delete(0, END)
        popup("Enter 0s and 1s only")


def bth(number):
    number = str(number)
    if not len(number) % 4 == 0:
        number = ('0'*(4-len(number) % 4)) + number
    diction = {'0000': 0, '0001': 1, '0010': 2, '0011': 3, '0100': 4, '0101': 5, '0110': 6, '0111': 7, '1000': 8, '1001': 9, '1010': 'A', '1011': 'B', '1100': 'C', '1101': 'D', '1110': 'E', '1111': 'F'}
    h, g = '', ''
    y, z = 0, 4
    while y < len(number):
        g = number[y:z]
        h = h + str(diction[g])
        y += 4
        z += 4
    return h

def bintohexa(number):
    number=str(number)
    bin_set= {'0','1'}
    x = number
    x=set(x)
    if bin_set == x or x == {'0'} or x == {'1'}:
        return bth(str(number))
    else:
        e_D.delete(0, END)
        e_O.delete(0, END)
        e_H.delete(0, END)
        popup("Enter 0s and 1s only")

# Decimal to Binary, Octal And hexa


def decitobin(number):
    number = int(number)
    s =''
    while number>0.1:
        a = number % 2
        number = number/2
        s = s+str(int(a))
    return int(s[::-1])


def decitooctal(number):
    number = int(number)
    s=''
    while number>0.1:
        a=number%8
        number=number/8
        s=s+str(int(a))
    return int(s[::-1])


def decitohexa(number):
    number=int(number)
    diction={'0':'0','1':'1','2':'2','3':'3','4':'4','5':'5','6':'6','7':'7','8':'8','9':'9','10':'A','11':'B','12':'C','13':'D','14':'E','15':'F'}
    s=''
    while(number>0):
        a=number%16
        number=number/16
        number=int(number)
        s=s+diction[str(a)]
    return s[::-1]

# Octal to Binary, Decimal and hexadecimal


def octaltobin(number):
    number=str(number)
    number = octaltodeci(number)
    h=decitobin(number)
    return h


def octaltodeci(number):
    leng = len(number)
    b= 0
    for i in number:
        c = int(i) * pow(8,leng - 1)
        b = b + c
        leng = leng  -1
    return b


def octaltohexa(number):
    number =octaltobin(number)
    h = bintohexa(number)
    return h

# Hexdecimal to binary, Deci, octal


def hexatobin(number):
    number=str(number)
    diction={'0':'0000','1':'0001','2':'0010','3':'0011','4':'0100','5':'0101','6':'0110','7':'0111','8':'1000','9':'1001','A':'1010','B':'1011','C':'1100','D':'1101','E':'1110','F':'1111','a':'1010','b':'1011','c':'1100','d':'1101','e':'1110','f':'1111'}
    h,g='',''
    y,z=0,4
    for i in number:
        h = h + str(diction[i])
    return int(h)


def hexatodeci(number):
    leng = len(number)
    b= 0
    diction = {'A':10,'B':11,'C':12,'D':13,'E':14,'F':15,'a':10,'b':11,'c':12,'d':13,'e':14,'f':15}
    for i in number:
        if i.isdigit():
            c = int(i) * pow(16,leng - 1)
            b = b + c
        else:
            c =diction[i] * pow(16,leng - 1)
            b = b + c
        leng = leng  -1
    return int(b)


def hexatooctal(number):
    number=str(number)
    diction={'0':'0000','1':'0001','2':'0010','3':'0011','4':'0100','5':'0101','6':'0110','7':'0111','8':'1000','9':'1001','A':'1010','B':'1011','C':'1100','D':'1101','E':'1110','F':'1111','a':'1010','b':'1011','c':'1100','d':'1101','e':'1110','f':'1111'}
    diction2={'000':0,'001':1,'010':2,'011':3,'100':4,'101':5,'110':6,'111':7}
    g,f,j,h='','','',''
    y,z=0,3
    for i in number:
        h = h + str(diction[i])
    if not len(h)%3 ==0:
        h =  ('0'*(3-len(h)%3)) + h
    while(y<len(h)):
        f = h[y:z]
        j = j + str(diction2[f])
        y+=3
        z+=3
    if int(j[0]) == 0:
        j = j[1:]
    return int(j)



def binary():
    b1 = e_b.get()
    e_O.delete(0, END)
    e_D.delete(0, END)
    e_H.delete(0, END)
    e_D.insert(0, bintodeci(b1))
    e_O.insert(0, bintooctal(b1))
    e_H.insert(0, bintohexa(b1))
def Decimal():
    d1 = e_D.get()
    e_b.delete(0, END)
    e_O.delete(0, END)
    e_H.delete(0, END)
    e_H.insert(0, decitohexa(d1))
    e_O.insert(0, decitooctal(d1))
    e_b.insert(0, decitobin(d1))
def Octal():
    o2 = e_O.get()
    e_b.delete(0, END)
    e_D.delete(0, END)
    e_H.delete(0, END)
    e_H.insert(0, octaltohexa(o2))
    e_D.insert(0, octaltodeci(o2))
    e_b.insert(0, octaltobin(o2))

def hexad():
    h2 = e_H.get()
    e_b.delete(0, END)
    e_O.delete(0, END)
    e_D.delete(0, END)
    e_O.insert(0, hexatooctal(h2))
    e_D.insert(0, hexatodeci(h2))
    e_b.insert(0, hexatobin(h2))

def button_clear():
    button_Convert.config(state=NORMAL)
    e_b.configure(state='normal')
    e_D.configure(state='normal')
    e_O.configure(state='normal')
    e_H.configure(state='normal')
    e_b.config(font=('helvetica',10,'bold'))
    e_D.config(font=('helvetica',10,'bold'))
    e_O.config(font=('helvetica',10,'bold'))
    e_H.config(font=('helvetica',10,'bold'))
    
    e_b.delete(0, END)
    e_O.delete(0, END)
    e_D.delete(0, END)
    e_H.delete(0, END)

def god():
    e_b.config(font=('helvetica',10,'bold','italic'))
    e_D.config(font=('helvetica',10,'bold','italic'))
    e_O.config(font=('helvetica',10,'bold','italic'))
    e_H.config(font=('helvetica',10,'bold','italic'))
    
    if e_b.get() == '' and e_O.get() == '' and e_D.get() == '' and e_H.get() == '':
        popup("Enter the values")
    else:
        num_1 = e_b.get()
        num_2 = e_D.get()
        num_3 = e_O.get()
        num_4 = e_H.get()
        if num_1.isdigit():
            binary()


        if num_2.isdigit():
            Decimal()

        if num_3.isdigit():
            Octal()
        lyst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
                '9']
        x =10
        b=0
        while(b<10):
            for i in num_4:
                if i in lyst:
                    hexad()
            b=b+1
        e_b.configure(state='readonly')
        e_D.configure(state='readonly')
        e_O.configure(state='readonly')
        e_H.configure(state='readonly')
        button_Convert.config(state=DISABLED)



def run():
    

    x=100
    while (x>=0):
        button_clear()
        god()
        x-=1
#run()
button_c = Button(root, text="Reset", padx=4, command=button_clear,bg='OrangeRed')
button_c.grid(row=4,column=0)
button_Convert = Button(root, text="Convert", command=god, padx=20, pady=10, bg='MediumSlateBlue')
button_Convert.grid(row=4, column=2)
root.resizable(True,True)
root.mainloop()
```

The full description of error was

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\machineLearning\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-2-c633423615e5>", line 302, in god
    binary()
  File "<ipython-input-2-c633423615e5>", line 243, in binary
    e_D.insert(0, bintodeci(b1))
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\machineLearning\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3051, in insert
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'insert', index, string)
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!entry2 insert index text"
```

Please help with this error

Comment: The error indicates that `bintodeci(b1)` returns `None` which the exception when it is used in `e_D.insert(...)`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hey man,thanks for replying,you can run the program in your system and tell me how is it

Comment: Worked for me. No issue

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the user enters an invalid input `bintodeci()` returns `None`, so there you should have to return an empty string.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.